# Referencing an aliased subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query :

```
select
        A.A_ID,
        B.Lib,
        A.Lib,
        C.Lib,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM X WHERE A.A_ID = X.A_ID) AS countX,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Y WHERE A.A_ID = Y.A_ID) AS countY,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Z WHERE A.A_ID = Z.A_ID) AS countZ
    from
        A
    left outer join
        C
            on A.C_ID=C.C_ID
    left outer join
        B
            on A.B_ID=B.B_ID
    WHERE
        countX = 2 AND countY = 3
    ORDER BY 
        countZ DESC;
```

But this gives me the following error:

> SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "COL_5_0_" : identificateur non
>   valide

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Use a subquery or CTE.  Your `GROUP BY` makes no sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below,  i think you missed  type group by it would be order by

```
with cte as
(

select
        A.A_ID,
        B.Lib,
        A.Lib,
        C.Lib,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM X WHERE A.A_ID = X.A_ID) AS countX,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Y WHERE A.A_ID = Y.A_ID) AS countY,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Z WHERE A.A_ID = Z.A_ID) AS countZ
    from
        A
    left outer join
        C
            on A.C_ID=C.C_ID
    left outer join
        B
            on A.B_ID=B.B_ID
) select * from cte where countX = 2 AND countY = 3
    Order BY 
    countZ DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I think you missed the `AS` keyword after `WITH cte`